# How to draw a polyline under street names in MapBox Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-android-nav

Currently I'm drawing polyline using **LineLayer** and adding it to the map using `style.addLayer(lineLayer)`. I noticed that polyline is drawn on top of the street labels. I want to get it under the labels in the map.

I found the method `style.addLayerBelow(lineLayer, <belowLayerId>)` method will resolve this but couldn't find the correct id to use as **belowLayerId**. Can anyone please help me on this matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What style are you using? You can view the style in Mapbox Studio (https://studio.mapbox.com) and see the order of the style's layers. If you're using Mapbox Streets `Style.MAPBOX_STREETS`, the street label id is `road-label`:

[image]

Or you can print each layer ID in the Android Studio logcat to see the layer order. The second code block area in https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/styling-map/#retrieving-a-map-layer has info about printing out all of the layers in the `Style`.

Comment: The label name `road-label` could resolve my problem. Thank you very much for the explanation. Earlier I tried printing only SymbolLayers but I could only found the layers like `road-label-street,
road-label-secondary-tertiary,
road-label-primary,
road-label-motorway-trunk,
road-shields-black,
road-shields-white,
rail-label` But none of them worked for me. The labelId `road-label` solved my problem.

Comment: Awesome, glad that you got it working. Happy building with Mapbox! Please consider marking my answer as correct :)